# When I malloc more space for a string within an array of strings, the array of strings duplicates some strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, malloc, strcpy

I have an array of strings, and I am trying to malloc more space for one of those strings so I can change the value of the string.

```
int catenate_strings (char** arr, int index1, int index2) { 
    char *new_string;
    new_string = malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
    if (new_string == NULL) {
        printf("\nError allocating memory\n");
    }   

    strcpy(new_string, arr[index1]);
    strcat(new_string, arr[index2]);
    arr[index1] = new_string;
}
```

However when I run my code, it will work for some instances, but in others it will duplicate the string at index1 and put it at index1 + 1 as well.

Comment: Are you trying to "resize" a string?

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Memory is leaking when you do `arr[index1] = new_string`, you are losing the previous string.

Comment: I am trying to resize the space allocated for the string so I can put a longer string there.

Comment: Another possibility is overflowing the buffer of `new_string`

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some problems:

1. Memory leak in `arr[index1] = new_string` because you are not freeing the old buffer.
2. Buffer overflow if the result string is longer than 1000 bytes.
3. Not returning any value from catenate_strings despite the function having return value int.

If all entries in `arr` are allocated using `malloc` then you can use `realloc`.

```
int catenate_strings (char** arr, int index1, int index2)
{ 
    // Resize buffer to hold old string + new string (+ terminating null byte!)
    char * const new_string = realloc(strlen(arr[index1]) + strlen(arr[index2]) + 1);
    if (new_string == NULL) {
        printf("\nError allocating Memory, cannot resize string\n");
        return -1;
    }   
    strcat(new_string, arr[index2]);
    arr[index1] = new_string;

    return 0;
}
```

The duplication to `index+1` comes not from the shown code but from somewhere else in your code.